# How do I delete files on a bootable osx Catalina disk from another bootup disk?

Tags: hard-drive, startup

My friend's 2016 iMac keeps crashing on restart after trying to install the latest Catalina update. The problem seems to be not enough disk space, he only has about 16 GB free on his internal Mac HD.

I had him boot up in recovery mode and install a fresh system on an external HD. Now I am trying to get into the MacHD drive to clean up some space but I can't get in to his files. Under 'Users' I just see 'Shared'. Nothing shows up in his application folder either. I am able to see some system files but not the personalised ones.

I tried changing permissions for the Mac HD to read & write but still no lock. I had him do it first over the phone but he is a total novice so ending up using Anydesk to access his computer remotely. Any suggestions of how I can clean up some space? Or can I cancel and ongoing update on restart with a key command?

Comment: 16 GB is more than enough  space fo an update; there’s something else going on.  Does your friend have encryption enabled?  Have you tried booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: His disk checks out fine using disk utility in recovery mode. It crashes when trying to boot in safe mode same as regular boot. In regular mode it seems it is updating to about 85% and then crashes. This happened after my friend downloaded the latest Catalina update. Not sure about the encryption, don't think so. How can I tell if the disk is encrypted when looking at it from another os x system on an external drive?

Comment: @ThorMadsen If the drive is encrypted, macOS will prompt for a password to mount the drive. This definitely seems like your installation of macOS is corrupted. Try reinstalling macOS (This doesn't erase data). https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac

Comment: If its crashing while booting in Safe Mode, there’s definitely an issue with the system. Recovery is a slimmed down version of macOS.  Before reinstalling, there are two things to try:  see if there is a local APFS snapshot to revert to and try installing a clean version of Catalina on a USB thumb drive (32 GB is fine for this).  To do the first, issue the command `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /`. Post your output to the question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Is your Mac running a beta version of macOS? There is a known bug where the system crashes with lower amounts of space in Catalina. You should try resetting the NVRAM first. Then, you can also try a reset of the SMC for power related issues. To delete files off of the Internal Drive, boot up on the bootable drive and go to Finder and click on the Internal Drive. If FileVault was enabled, then macOS will prompt for the login password of one of the users on the problem instance of macOS. This will unlock and mount the drive. Then, you can use Finder and Terminal to navigate the files and delete.

Comment: Both NVRAM and SMC were reset. The problem is not getting into the Mac HD harddrive from outside but that I can't see the important files. It seems I only see the raw installation files and none of the personal files. Under /Users his user account doesn't appear. The application folder is empty. Some of the folders are greyed out but I can still look inside them.

Comment: First, try running First Aid. If that doesn't work, then use macOS Recovery or a Bootable macOS Installer to reinstall macOS. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac. This doesn't erase data.

Comment: I can't reinstall system from Recovery mode, says not enuff space